# What to use javascript array or object or mix of them?

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript array or object or maybe something mixed for this task:

I have this attributes:
customer
item
barcode

```
So I will fill all fields with loop like this:
customer = 1
item = 1
barcode = 5555

customer = 1
item = 2 
barcode = 6666
```

the combination of customer and item will be unique, so I want to directly access the value (barcode), like this:

"give me the barcode value where customer = 1 and item 1, so the result must be 5555"

I don't want to use loop to find the value, I want direct access.

Thanks!

Currently, I have created example script. My question is there anything better?

```
function cacheBarcodes() {
    var results = [];
    // Here the database is pushing all 100k+ records to the array
    results.push(['1', '1', '5555']);
    results.push(['1', '2', '6666']);

    return results;
}

function getBarcode(results,customer,item) {

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var db_customer = results[i][0];
        var db_item = results[i][1];
        var db_barcode = results[i][2];

        if (db_customer == customer && db_item == item ) {
            return db_barcode;
        }
    }

}
results = cacheBarcodes();
alert(getBarcode(results,'1','1'));
```

Comment: And you're trying to replicate a database in JavaScript because? This is a job for an SQL query.

Comment: I want to cache database results

Comment: Although possible, I doubt there will be any performance gains for < 1k records. If there are more then that you can try generating a hash of customer , item and storing it as a property of an object, value being the barcode.

Comment: @JaredSmith please look at my example, which is better, the hashed method or to loop every time I need the result?

Comment: Probably the hash method actually.

Comment: I'm trying to not use the database query for each combination of customer ID + item ID, because I need to search 1k items every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, need to get the most important thing out of the way: **this is a terrible idea**. Don't actually do this unless you are *way* beyond sure that you need to:

```
var salt = "___";
var genKey = function(r) {
  return '' + r.customer + salt + r.item;
};

var barcodes = {};
records.forEach(function(r) {
  var key = genKey(r);
  barcodes[key] = r.barcode;
});
```

Now you can call `genKey` with the record to access the barcode for the cost of a function call and hash lookup instead of looping through the array of records. As Anirudha pointed out in the comments you probably gain nothing by this. It gets a little better (in terms of cleanliness, not performance) if you put an interface on it:

```
class Lookup {
  constructor () {
    this._barcodes = {};
  }

  _genKey (customer, item) {
    return '' + customer + '___' + item;
  }

  addRecord (r) {
    let key = this._genKey(r.customer, r.item);
    this._barcodes[key] = r.barcode;
    return this;
  }

  getBarcode (customer, item) {
    let key = this._genKey(customer, item);
    return this._barcodes[key];
  }
};
```